# Symfony2 - assetic background images on subdomain

Tags: css, symfony, assetic, symfony-2.2

I have two bundles in Symfony 2.2

*1. FrontBundle on domaint.tld*

- domain.tld/symfony/src/Comapny/FrontBundle/Resources/public/css
- domain.tld/symfony/src/Comapny/FrontBundle/Resources/public/images
- domain.tld/symfony/src/Comapny/FrontBundle/Resources/public/js

*2. AdminBundle on admin.domain.tld*

- domain.tld/symfony/src/Comapny/AdminBundle/Resources/public/css (custom.css)
- domain.tld/symfony/src/Comapny/AdminBundle/Resources/public/images (image.png)
- domain.tld/symfony/src/Comapny/AdminBundle/Resources/public/js

*domain.tld/symfony/src/Comapny/AdminBundle/Resources/public/css/custom.css*

```
div.image {
    background-image: url(../images/image.png);
}
```

*domain.tld/symfony/app/config/config.yml*

```
debug:          "%kernel.debug%"
use_controller: false
bundles:        [ AdminBundle, FrontBundle ]
read_from:      "%kernel.root_dir%/../../public_html/"
write_to:      "%kernel.root_dir%/../../public_html/"
filters:
    cssrewrite: ~
```

*domain.tld/symfony/app/config/routing.yml*

```
admin:
    host: "admin.domaint.tld"
    resource: "@AdminBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

front: 
    host: "domain.tld"
    resource: "@FrontBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

*domain.tld/symfony/src/Company/AdminBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig*

```
{% stylesheets
'bundles/admin/css/custom.css'
filter='cssrewrite,?yui_css'
 %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}"/>
{% endstylesheets %}
```

i use

```
app/console cache:clear
app/console assets:install ../public_html --symlink   
app/console assetic:dump
```

--

**PROBLEM**

On domain.tld works everything OK, but problem is on subdomain.

source code from admin.domain.tld

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/8d488cd_custom_11.css"/>
```

8d488cd_custom_11.css

```
div.image {
    background-image: url(../../bundles/admin/images/image.png);
}
```

from firebug

```
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://admin.domain.tld/bundles/admin/images/image.png"
```

**Any idea how to correct code or configuration to (css backgrounds) working for subdomain and root domain too ?**

Comment: You want to access the same resource files from `admin.domain.com` and `domain.com`?

Comment: @cheesemacfly no, each bundle has own resources (each has own template)

Comment: Do you have the expected files/symlink under `web/bundles/admin` on your server?

Comment: im developing on localhost, but thats not essence. yes symlink works.
css are corectly loaded (because assetic:dump create css and js). all is in public_html root

Comment: So you are saying that the file `web/bundles/admin/images/image.png` exists but when you try to reach it with `http://admin.domain.tld/bundles/admin/images/image.png` you get a 404?

Comment: yes exist on server in `/public_html/bundles/admin/images/image.png` so its working with `http://domain.tld/bundles/admin/images/image.png` but not for `http://admin.domain.tld/bundles/admin/images/image.png` - yes its logical - but how solve this ? :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23984/discussion-between-patie-and-cheesemacfly)